# Building Zip of images with PHPArchive does not work with variable string

Tags: php, post, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to generate a zip file from an html post. The post data is a string of urldecoded image names separated by commas.

If I manually enter the string as the $files array, the zip is generated correctly. However, if I use a variable that represents the string nothing is generated. I don't see any errors either. See the commented lines for a specific example of the variable string.

I can't see how one would work and the other wouldn't. The post data will obviously vary, so I need to figure out how to make the variable work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<?php
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$imstr = "'" . str_replace(",", "', '", $raw_post) . "'";
echo($imstr);
// echo($imstr); returns 'image--11-15-2013 (1).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (2).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (3).jpeg'
$files = array($imstr);
// This works as expected -> $files = array('image--11-15-2013 (1).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (2).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (3).jpeg');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
?>
```

Comment: windows or *nix? (file name issues on windows is possible.)

Comment: linux - CentOS. Thanks.

Comment: But you didn't split your `$imstr` variable into an array. You're basically passing a string that contains multiple file names to `$zip->addFile()`

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what I needed to do, since manually entering a string of names works correctly. Like: $files = array('image--11-15-2013 (1).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (2).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (3).jpeg');

What should I be doing differently to turn $imstr into an array?

Comment: It depends how does your input look like. Is the string really url-encoded? Because it doesn't look like so from your comments in the code

Comment: No, the initial values were encoded, but I decode them client-side, so the string is not url encoded.

echo($imstr); returns 'image--11-15-2013 (1).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (2).jpeg', image--11-15-2013 (3).jpeg'

Comment: In that case splitting by comma should probably work, unless the files have commas in their names. So basically you [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by `,` (remove the `str_replace` line)

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. I used:
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$imarr = explode(',', $raw_post);
$files = array($imarr);
Is that what you meant?

Comment: almost.. drop the last statement. you just need `$imarr`

Comment: Hazzaa! That did it. The resulting zip file isn't opening / streaming as it should, but I think that's a different issue - it does get created on the server. Thanks for the help!